# Need help for multilanguage in django

Tags: django

I want to develop a site with 2 languages in a django site but i have no idea for this. Are there anything in django that support me to do that? Please show me the way and give me the document if you can.

Thanks

Comment: You have just to look for internationalization at djangoproject.com

Answer (score 0):

Please [consult the documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/i18n/) regarding Django's internationalization capabilities and how to manage localization.